# Calculate euclidian distance in groups inside a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, euclidean-distance

I have to calculate distance in 350 groups of a matrix.

Each group have 5 rows (AA;BB;CC;DD;EE) and 7 columns (Codes;ClusterID; AA;BB;CC;DD;EE). The second column is for identify each group (ClusterID).

```
Codes; ClusterID;AA;BB;CC;DD;EE
AA;171;1.450;0.896;0.786;0.994;0.949 
BB;171;0.896;1.090;1.000;0.954;1.050
CC;171;0.786;1.000;1.300;0.896;1.010
DD;171;0.994;0.954;0.896;1.170;0.951
EE;171;0.949;1.050;1.010;0.951;1.020
AA;343;1.670;0.699;0.959;0.934;0.728
BB;343;0.699;1.610;1.170;1.440;0.445
CC;343;0.959;1.170;1.380;0.268;0.888
DD;343;0.934;1.440;0.268;1.830;0.916
EE;343;0.728;0.445;0.888;0.916;1.820
```

I calculated distance for one group extracted it for the big matrix.

But I know I need to create a loop to repeat the process in each group automatically.

Finally the output should be as follows:

```
$171
AA              BB              CC              DD              EE 
AA                  0.63415219  0.85395140  0.50436098  0.57600608
BB      0.63415219              0.33935822  0.30882519  0.07360706
CC      0.85395140  0.33935822              0.53586659  0.34101906
DD      0.50436098  0.30882519  0.53586659              0.27741485
EE      0.57600608  0.07360706  0.34101906  0.27741485    

$343
AA                  1.467449        1.172075        1.551263        1.466189
BB  1.467449                        1.369355        1.127683        1.898102
CC  1.172075        1.369355                        1.936672        1.452439
DD  1.551263        1.127683        1.936672                        1.751991
EE  1.466189        1.898102        1.452439        1.751991
```

I am beginner in  R, and I do not know if is possible to do it or how can I do.

Comment: Please share the code you're using for one group. Also, it would be really nice if you shared `dput(your_matrix[1:10, ])` for a copy/pasteable version of your sample data.

Comment: The matrix are:
c<-matrix(c(171,171,171,171,171,2.390,0.659,1.050,0.710,0.178,0.659,1.580,0.891,0.735,0.936,1.050,0.891,1.200,0.881,0.955,0.710,0.735,0.881,2.680,0.198,0.178,0.936,0.955,0.198,2.880), nrow = 5,ncol=6,dimnames = list(c("AA","BB","CC","DD","EE"),c("ClusterID","AA","BB","CC","DD","EE")))The code are: m<- as.matrix(dist(c))